# How to cancel timeout if user performs click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display a pop-up window after 10 second if any other click event is not performed. i.e. I displayed the pop-up window after 10 as:

```
setTimeout( "jQuery('#rollup-page-Modal').modal('show');",10000 );
```

Now there are few pop-up windows which will be displayed once clicked as:

```
jQuery(".more-info").click(function(event){
    jQuery("#more-info-modal").modal('show');
    event.preventDefault();
});

jQuery(".call-now").click(function(event){
    jQuery("#request-callback-modal").modal('show');
    event.preventDefault();
});

jQuery(".popup-send-quote").click(function(){
    jQuery("#request-callback-modal").modal('hide');
    jQuery("#callback-thankyou-modal").modal('show');
});
```

Now I want, the first pop-up window (which will be displayed after 10 sec) should not be displayed if any other pop-up windows is displayed or any other click event is performed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "any *other* click event"? so which is *the* click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to store the `id` of the `timeout` in a variable, then you can use [`window.clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout) to clear the timeout when a click happens in the document:

```
var timer = setTimeout( "jQuery('#rollup-page-Modal').modal('show');",10000 );
$(document).on("click",function(){
  clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

first the timeout code:

```
var timeout = setTimeout( function () {
    jQuery('#rollup-page-Modal').modal('show');
},10000 );
```

now that it's in a var you can cancel it elsewhere in the code:

```
jQuery(".more-info").click(function(event){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    jQuery("#more-info-modal").modal('show');
    event.preventDefault();
});

jQuery(".call-now").click(function(event){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    jQuery("#request-callback-modal").modal('show');
    event.preventDefault();
});

jQuery(".popup-send-quote").click(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    jQuery("#request-callback-modal").modal('hide');
    jQuery("#callback-thankyou-modal").modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. `cancelTimeout` does not work, perhaps it would be `clearTimeout`. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Add a flag

```
var didClick = false;

jQuery(".more-info").click(function(event){
    jQuery("#more-info-modal").modal('show');
    event.preventDefault();
    didClick = true;
});

jQuery(".call-now").click(function(event){
    jQuery("#request-callback-modal").modal('show');
    event.preventDefault();
    didClick = true;
});

jQuery(".popup-send-quote").click(function(){
    jQuery("#request-callback-modal").modal('hide');
    jQuery("#callback-thankyou-modal").modal('show');
    didClick = true;
});
```

then set it to false before timeout

```
didClick = false;
setTimeout(function() {
    if (!didClick) {
        jQuery('#rollup-page-Modal').modal('show');
    }
},10000 );
```